# Headless installation login

Tags: headless, login

I'm looking for an workaround to login into raspian lite version via n/w. I don't want to utilize '''raspi-config''' command for enabling ssh, as display or keyboard are not connected to raspberry pi

Comment: Any one remember if the serial console is enabled by default?  I've no spare Pi at the mo (something to do with the season and *toys* not being allowed) to check...

Answer (score 2):

I assume n/w means network.

You need to put a file called ssh in the boot (FAT) directory of the Pi.

SSH will then be enable when the Pi next boots.

Comment: Yes, I mean network. How to put file in headless version?

Comment: Put the SD card in a SD card reader connected to a working computer.  Use the computer to create the file.

Answer (score 1):

You could also clone a SD card with a OS installation where the ssh daemon is already configured using a SD Card reader.

Just so you have full information, the Raspberry Pi config tool runs on any normal terminal session---without a monitor or keyboard connected to the Pi---such xterm, vt220, &c:

```
$ sudo raspi-config
```

Of course, that doesn't help your "headless" configuration issue, as you still need a tty or terminal session, but I wanted to be sure yu knew you could connect through the USB ports and still use raspi-config without a GUI.

SFH